# Actionlink with both routevalues and htmlattributes - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I am trying to both have some route values and html attributes on my `ActionLink`.

So, I have the following code. The first three parameters is text, action name and controller. Then I add the route values, and then I try to add the HTML attributes.

```
@Html.ActionLink("What is this", "Pages", "Root", new { @slug = "what-is-this" },new{@class="dropdown-toggle", @data-toggle="dropdown"})
```

When I run the website I get an error message saying the view with this actionlink, it gives the `External component has thrown an exception.`

So, I guess my question is: How to add html attributes to this action link? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `@data-toogle`, but rather you need to use an underscore. So you link should be like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("What is this", "Pages", "Root", new { slug = "what-is-this" },new{@class="dropdown-toggle", data_toggle="dropdown"})
```

The rest will be done by MVC and your `data_toggle` will be converted to `data-toggle`. Also, there is no need to use `@` with every item. You use it only when you use reserved C# keywords like `class`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in `@data-toggle`.

You cannot have a dash in the name. If you need the "-" rendered on the client, you can use the "_" and MVC will render the "-"

```
@Html.ActionLink("What is this", "Pages", "Root", new { @slug = "what-is-this" },new{@class="dropdown-toggle", @data_toggle="dropdown"})
```